# React Native upgrade vs React Native New app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I built a ReactNative application (version 0.47), in the past. Upgrade to latest version (0.60) messed up a lot. If I build a new ReactNative app on with the same bundle Id for iOS and same app Id for Android, will it work on the upgrade cycle for app or Is there a better way to do things. My original app had the following dependencies

- React Navigation
- React Navigation gesture handler
- React Cookies Handler
- React Geolocation

All of these dependencies created several upgrade issues and fixing it takes for ever. I think I am better off building a new application, exporting contents from existing app rather than fixing it all the way.

I'd appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to reinstall everything in `package.json` if you make an entirely new app. I would recommend just using `react-native upgrade`. The react folks also provide a nice [upgrade tool](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) thats useful to compare differences between files that change between upgrades. Only as a last resort would i create an entirely new app and copy files over.

[Upgrading React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I totally agree with you. I've been trying to upgrade my app with in-built command. Android has been giving me a very tough time, especially on the packages I listed (React native, navigation gesture handler). Compilation and execution errors of all kinds.
I had similar problems with iOS and I was able to fix them all. But Android does not budge

Comment: What you could also do, is wipe out your node_modules and just reinstall after the react native upgrade.